# Can NVLink be used to reduce the overhead of cross-GPU hardware accelerated content compositing on a multi-monitor system?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, dwm

I have two GPUs installed in a Windows 10 Pro for Workstations system in order to support five 4K monitors. At the moment I'm using an RTX 2080Ti as my primary card, and a GTX 1050Ti as my secondary card.

When hardware accelerated content (e.g. video) is shown within an application, it is rendered on one of the GPUs; usually the 2080Ti, but the system/application is free to pick for itself. If the windowed content is moved to a monitor, which is connected to the other GPU, the desktop window manager (DWM) composites the content. This involves transferring the render buffer from one card to the other, possibly with a swap to system memory in between, which is slow and inefficient.

This overhead can be seen in task manager: the card which is doing the hardware acceleration will show GPU time going into 3D or video decode, the card which the monitor is attached to will sohw GPU time going into copy operations, and dwm.exe will show high CPU and GPU usage along with increased PF delta. I have confirmed that this is not a problem with the 1050Ti being underpowered; forcing a browser to use the 1050Ti for hardware acceleration results in perfectly acceptable performance when the content is shown on a monitor connected to that card, and MPC-HC with madVR (which swaps the target GPU based on the display the window is on) can happily play high bitrate 2160p60 media on that card.

In some cases this can be solved by getting the application to pick the other GPU, if I know I'm going to be using it on a particular monitor, but that's inconvenient and isn't workable for web browsers and other multi-window programs. The compositing performance impact is significant enough to prevent reliable playback of 1440p or 2160p YouTube videos in Chrome and Firefox when the window is on one of the other monitors. Disabling hardware acceleration isn't an acceptable option.

I understand that NVLink can enable GPU memory pooling and/or sharing in certain configurations. However, my last experience with linked GPUs was with SLI in the late 2000s,  back when you couldn't run more than one monitor in total when SLI was enabled, and I don't know much about the practical behaviour of NVLink today.

I know that NVLink can operate in different modes (SLI mode, TCC mode) and the capabilities and behaviours of the GPUs vary depending on those modes. I understand that TCC mode is typically only supported between professional (Quadro) cards and the display outputs are disabled when TCC mode is in use; this would make sense for compute cluster operation. I have read conflicting information about multi-monitor support with NVLink and SLI mode, and I am also not clear on whether "two GPUs with an NVLink bridge installed" and "two GPUs with an NVLink bridge installed in NV-SLI mode" are different concepts.

Given that NVLink provides an interface through which two GPUs can access each other's memory, I could foresee that Windows might leverage this (most likely within DXGI) to significantly reduce the overhead of display compositing in the window manager.

Based on the above, my questions are:

- What is the practical distinction (if any) between two consumer RTX GPUs with no NVLink bridge installed, two consumer RTX GPUs with an NVLink bridge installed, and two consumer RTX GPUs with an NVLink bridge installed in "SLI" mode (is this NV-SLI?)
- Does installing an NVLink bridge between two consumer RTX GPUs (i.e. not in TCC mode) still allow all of the display outputs on both of the cards to be used, or are some of the outputs disabled? If NVLink bridged cards and "SLI mode" *are* in fact distinct concepts, does display output availability change depending on whether SLI is enabled?
- Most importantly, will NVLink assist with the problem of hardware accelerated window compositing overheads in Windows 10? If not, has this changed at all in Windows 11?